# probability that {x + y} = {x} + {y}, for the point (x, y) selected randomly from the square

Tags: probability

> An experiment consists of randomly selecting a point $(x, y)$ from the square defined in the Cartesian plane by the vertices $(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$.
>
> (a) Construct a probability space $(\Omega, A, \mathbb{P})$ of the aforementioned experiment, identifying precisely and mathematically the three elements that make up the space.
>
> (b) Given a real number $r$, define $\{r\}$ as the closest integer to $r$. Calculate the probability that $\{x + y\} = \{x\} + \{y\}$, for the point $(x, y)$ selected randomly from the square. **Answer:** 3/4

What I've done so far:

a)

$\Omega$: the set of all points $(x, y)$ in the unit square, that is, $\Omega = \{(x, y)|0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1\}$.

$\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, the Borel sigma algebra of subsets of $\Omega$, which contains all the possible events that can occur in the experiment.

So, $$\mathbb{P}(E)=\frac{S_E}{1} = \iint_E 1 dx dy$$ (Since it is a unit square)

b) I made a square and divided it into four equal squares. I had the following reasoning, for {r} to be close to r, it must be within the area of one of the four squares. Then it follows that:

As {x} ∈ {0,1} , {y} ∈ {0,1}, so {x+y} ∈ {0,1,2}

If {x}=0, 0 ≤ x < 1/2

If {x}=1, 1/2 ≤ x ≤ 1

If {y}=0, 0 ≤ y < 1/2

If {y}=1, 1/2 ≤ y < 1

Now for {x+y} what would be a good way to do this? I thought about making lines that cut the square diagonally, but I think that would be too complicated to define the intervals. Is there any simpler way? I pretty much did this part by trial and error, and I'm not confident of the answer so far

Comment: Can you identify the set of points such that $ \{ x + y \} = \{ x \} + \{ y \}$? EG Condition accordingly to how $x, y$ compared to 0.5, and $x+y$ compares to 0.5, 1.5$.

Comment: Can you identify the event $\{(x,y) \in \Omega : \{x+y\} = 1\}$ without reference to the function $\{x+y\}$?

Comment: The places where $\{ x + y \} \neq \{ x \} + \{ y \}$ are fewer and easier to describe than the places where $\{ x + y \} = \{ x \} + \{ y \}$. You might try attacking the problem that way.

Comment: I would draw the diagonal lines. Yes, you might then be looking at shapes that are not squares, but since there are only three possible values of $\{ x + y \}$ you will not need many diagonal lines.